# How to write case class for enum column in Apache Spark Dataset?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, case-class, apache-spark-dataset

```
story1, 10, small
story2, 20, medium
sotry3, 3, small
story4, 50, xlarge
```

I want to convert my data to Dataset. I have a column name storyType (small, medium, large, xlarge). So I don't know how to write my case class in this situation

```
case class Story(name:String, point: Int, storyType: ???)
```

Comment: What is the type of the column?

Comment: all content of column is string but I want to convert this column to enum type.

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
sealed trait StoryType
case object small extends StoryType
case object medium extends StoryType
case object large extends StoryType
case object xlarge extends StoryType
```